# Can't make jsfiddle code work outside of jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

I found this code on jsfiddle and it works fine, inside of fiddle. But when I try to put it inside of my own HTML file I can't get it to work. I am sure I left something out of the script tag, but I just don't know what. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the fiddle: [Working Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MEwX6/)

P.S. The code is supposed to pull info from the URL and fill the form.

-Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Parser</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Your first name:
<br /><input name="name (awf_first)" id="name (awf_first)" /></p>

<p>Your last name:
<br /><input name="name (awf_last)" id="name (awf_last)" /></p>

<p>Your email:
<br /><input name="email" id="email" /></p>

<p>Your password:
<br /><input name="password" id="password" /></p>


<script>
var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to 
remove the `?`
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"But when I try to put it inside of my own HTML file I can't get it to work."* What does this mean? What is happening when you try the code? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: It's not reading the variables from the URL and filling the form.

Comment: And so, again I ask. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: The console error reads: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: Show a sample url. Also if `remove the ?` is on a new line it will produce an error.

Comment: If you're trying to process the query string, you should be using `window.location.search`, not `window.location.hash`.

Comment: In your fiddle, IDs are `name` and `email`, but in your real code the IDs are `name (awf_first)` and `name (awf_last)`. Do the parameters in the hash string match these IDs?

Comment: What is the value of `hashParams` on your website?

Comment: One other note: an ID like "name (awf_first)" would typically be URL encoded as "name+(awf_first)", so you'll likely need to decode that for document.getElementById to find the element.

Comment: @Quentin — since the hashParams array is coming from window.location, some form of URL encoding would come into play at that point. Although it may be "%20" rather than "+".

Comment: @craigmc — Ah! You calling it an ID at that point threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that `document.getElementById(p[0])` is not finding the `#name` and `#email` input elements.

This could be for two reasons:

1. **You don't have any elements with `id`s of: `name` and `email`.**

Check your elements to make sure that you have given them correct `id`s. Your code shows elements with `id`s of: `name (awf_first)` and `name (awf_last)`, when the `id`s should be: `name` and `email`.

2. You are attempting to find the element(s) prior to them being read into the DOM.

Make sure that the `script` comes AFTER the bulk of the HTML (just before the close of the `body` tag) as it is shown in the Fiddle, so that by the time you run that line, the element(s) will already be in the DOM.

Also, be aware that in your question, the line `// substr(1) to 
remove the '?'` is split across two lines and is currently causing an error in your code. And, within that comment change the back-ticks surrounding the `?` with single quotes.